# Getting error while using display tag

Tags: java, tags, struts2

I am using a display tag to display my table and it generating pagination on its own but when i click on the next page link i get

HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

I am using the display tab in combination with the struts tags

could any one please tell me what might be going on..?

Kaddy

Comment: please share you code snippets. specially you display tag usage in jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your resources are deployed in `WEB-INF`. because you can not access resources in `WEB-INF`. Accessing those will give this error.

I will suggest you check your project structure once again.